# Gettring a reference to a managed ProgressDialog

Tags: android

In my activity I need a `ProgressDialog` with a horizontal progress bar to visualise the progress of a background task. To make the activity care for the dialog e.g. in case of screen rotation, I would like to use a managed dialog created in `onCreateDialog`. The problem is that I need to update the progress bar of the dialog after it has been created and therefor I need a reference to the managed progress dialog: Does anyone know how to retrieve a reference to a dialog created by `onCreateDialog`?

At the moment I am storing a reference to the dialog created in `onCreateDialog`, but that my fail with a `InvalidArgumentException` in the `onFinished()` method after the screen has been rotated (and the activity has been recreated):

```
public final class MyActivity extends Activity {
  private static final int DIALOG_PROGRESS = 0;
  private ProgressDialog progressDialog = null;

  // [...]

  @Override
  protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case DIALOG_PROGRESS:
      progressDialog = createProgressDialog();
      return progressDialog;
    default:
      return super.onCreateDialog(id);
    }
  }

  // [...]

  public void updateProgress(int progress) {
    progressDialog.setProgress(0);
  }

  public void onFinished() {
    progressDialog.dismiss();
  }

  // [...]
}
```

I would have expected something like a `getDialog(int)` method in the `Activity` class to get a reference to a managed dialog, but this doesn't seem to exist. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I answer myself:

1. There really is no `getDialog(int)` method available in the `Activity` class.
2. Storing the reference like shown above works correctly -- the bug was something else...

The problem was, that the parallel thread, that called the `onFinished()` method called this method on the already destroyed activity, thus the accessed `ProgressDialog` instance is still existing but no longer a valid dialog. Instead another activity with another `ProgressDialog` has already been created by Android.

So all I needed to do was to make the background thread call the `onFinished()` method of the new activity and everything works fine. To switch the reference I override the `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` and `getLastNonConfigurationInstance()` methods of the `Activity` class.

The good thing of the shown example: Android really cares about recreating the new dialog after the screen orientation changed. So constructing the `ProgressDialog` that way is definitely easier than using `ProgressDialog.show()` where I would need to handle the dialog recreation on my own (the two methods described above would be a good place to do this.